# Crystal Report 13 loads very slowly, not only first time

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, crystal-reports

I'm using VB.net 4.5.2 and Crystal Reports version 13_0_17. I can't trace the process after the "CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource=crClientReportDoc".

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        strReportOption1 = Request.QueryString("strOption1")
        strReportOption2 = Request.QueryString("strOption2")
        strReportPath = Server.MapPath("ShareholderList.rpt")
        crClientReportDoc = clsRpt.fnProcessReport(strReportPath, strReportOption1, strReportOption2, Session("strSQL"), Session("strControlKey"))
        fnsetViewerProperties()
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crClientReportDoc
    End Sub
```

Every time load the Crystal report, it takes around 2 minutes. When I press the next page button, it will take another 2 minutes to load, but the result is just 1 line.

Is there anywhere I can check what the problem is on the Crystal Report that causes the page load to take that long. Also, when I press 'next page', that takes a long time to load again.

Debug output returned this

> Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
>   The thread 0x1868 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x30e8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   The thread 0x2a88 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
>   Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll

Comment: You really need to add a bit more to this question, as it is it is extremely hard to answer

Comment: what is the information you need?

Comment: Are you using `Response.Redirect()` at all?